# glmnet, categorical variable, group lasso?

Tags: categorical-data, survival, lasso, cox-model, glmnet

I am using glmnet for LASSO. My data set contains several continuous variables and one categorical variable (it has four levels). I wondered if I could treat three dummy variables as other continuous variables. Should I use a type of group LASSO approach for the three dummies?

Comment: Normally, yes, you keep your factors all together. There's several R packages that can do this, including `glmnet`.

Comment: @Glen_b What are the options in `glmnet` for running group lasso with categorical variables?  I don't see anything about categorical variables at https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf

Comment: See the `type.multinomial` argument to `glmnet`

Comment: perhaps leave dummies not penalized (as what you with intercept), unless you have a good reason to put a constraint on them. if so, just add dummies and impute zero penalty weights if you use glmnet implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware glmnet doesn't have this feature implemented yet. @Glen_b's suggestion of using type.multinomial is used to group variables across all responses in a multinomial model, but there's no way of grouping independent variables in a model. see

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grplasso/grplasso.pdf

for an alternative.